# BeautifulSoup, Selenium and Python, parsing by a tag

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup, webdriverwait

I'm trying to parse data from this website

https://findrulesoforigin.org/home/compare?reporter=392&partner=036&product=020130010

In particular, I am trying to get the data under **Criterion(ITC)**.  The text I want says **CC+ECT**

The information I want in html appears to be

```
<a class= js-glossary data-leg= "CC+ECT">
```

I'm new to web scraping and I tried the techniques taught in the tutorial but they didn't work. I heard about Selenium and tried this out too. However, this code didn't work either.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path = r"D:\Python work\driver\geckodriver.exe")
driver.get(r"https://findrulesoforigin.org/home/compare?reporter=392&partner=036&product=020130010")
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
data = soup.find_all("a", attrs= {"class":"js-glossary"})
```

The code results in an empty list.  I also read that I can pull out the data by treating the soup tag like a dictionary.  in this case

```
data["data-leg"]
```

Am I on the right track or am I way off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text you're trying to get generated dynamically by JavaScript. To get it you need to wait for its appearance:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path = r"D:\Python work\driver\geckodriver.exe")
driver.get(r"https://findrulesoforigin.org/home/compare?reporter=392&partner=036&product=020130010")
text = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[.="criterion(itc)"]/following-sibling::div').text)
print(text)
#  'CC + ECT'
```

Comment: Thank you! Your script works beautifully. I will have to read up more on the syntax you used as it is very advanced for me.

Comment: You can read more about Waits in Selenium [here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#waits)

Answer (score 1):

Seems you were pretty close. You may not even require *Beautiful Soup* if you are using *Selenium*. Using *Selenium* you need to induce *WebDriverwait* for the desired *element to be visible* and you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path = r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\geckodriver.exe')
  driver.get(r"https://findrulesoforigin.org/home/compare?reporter=392&partner=036&product=020130010")
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='lbl' and text()='criterion(itc)']//following::div[1]/a"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
                                  CC + ECT
  ```